# removing words that include anything that isn't letters regex

Tags: regex

I need a little help with my homework. Teacher recommended Regexr.com as the tool to use for this exercise.

in 1. the task is to use the letters a,k,t,l and mark out words that are 6 characters long and include those characters.

in 2. the task is to mark out all words that start with a.

problem i have in 1. is that one of the marked "words" contains a + before the marked text and i don't know how to exclude that whole word. Have tried working around the Regex but with no success.

`(([a,k,l,t]){6}\b)`

1. http://regexr.com/3clf6

in 2. i have the same problem but reverse. got some punctuation behind the marked words. which I can't seem to find any solution on.

```
(\ba\w*\b)
```

2. http://www.regexr.com/3clff

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to include the examples that aren't working here on SO.  I'm not clicking through to some random site

Comment: 1) I don't understand how are those letters are relevant to the match. Anyways you don't need the commas.
2) Your regex and results look correct. I don't see what you mean by "got some punctuation".

Comment: In general `all words` can't be described with Regular Expressions !! In fact, _language_ can't be described with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Maybe a positive lookahead is the right choice for the 2nd one then?

`/(?=a)(\b[^\s]*)/ig`

This regex checks if a word starts with an "a", doesn't consume the "a" and continues with`(\b[^\s]*)`from the same position on matching all non-whitespace characters. Note that without `\b` the `atest`part of a string `teatest` would also be matched.

---

Not sure what you mean with the first one, but for the second one you could use:

```
/a[^\s]+/ig
```

Test:

```
asdfasdfsdf => match
aaaa => match
akltaA:: => match
sdfA => no match
```

Comment: thank you but yours doesn't work properly due to it becoming a substring searcher, instead of searching for words starting with a.